# GulpJS not running on port defined on app.js expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, browser-sync

i had setup some gulp tasks and started gulp but gulp is running on port 3000 and my app config is to listen on port 4545 so it opens 3000 port but no any contents it displays output like Cannot GET /.
my project stucture is like

- controllers
- views
- public
- app.js
- gulpfile.js

so i want gulp to listen on port defined in app.js and watch changes on public flder.
 I have included gulp plugin like  gulp-plumber,gulp-browser-sync

and its my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
reload = browserSync.reload,
plumber = require('gulp-plumber')

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('public/javascripts/**/*.js')
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(reload({
                     stream: true
        }));
});


gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('public/stylesheets/**/*.css')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

// gulp.task('html', function() {
    // gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
        // .pipe(reload({
            // stream: true
        // }));
// });


gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('public/javascripts/**/*.js', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('public/stylesheets/**/*.css', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-nodemon`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon')

gulp.task('develop', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: 'app.js',
        ext: 'js',
    }).on('restart', function () {
        // a server restarted hook can be added here
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['develop']);
```

Basically it will restart automatically the server when you change a js file

Comment: I have tried gulp-nodemon and i got some error like child proccess spawn and then server runs on port 4545 but gulp doesnt run its tasks only nodemon runs

Comment: Post exactely what you do. You can run the other tasks before nodemon. or when you make changes in your files (with the watch) you can restart nodemon.

Comment: Totally stucked .. may be of newbie with gulpjs.. thanks for ur help